# How do I create a struct containing a nalgebra matrix with higher dimensions?

Tags: generics, rust

I want to create a `struct` that contains a `nalgebra::MatrixN` that is `U1` larger:

```
extern crate nalgebra as na;

use na::{DimName, DimNameAdd, DimNameSum, MatrixN, U1};

pub struct Homogenous<D: DimName>
where
    D: DimNameAdd<U1>,
{
    mat: na::MatrixN<f32, DimNameSum<D, U1>>,
}
```

I get the following error:

```
error[E0277]: cannot multiply `<<D as na::DimNameAdd<na::U1>>::Output as na::DimName>::Value` to `<<D as na::DimNameAdd<na::U1>>::Output as na::DimName>::Value`
 --> src/main.rs:9:5
  |
9 |     mat: na::MatrixN<f32, DimNameSum<D, U1>>,
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no implementation for `<<D as na::DimNameAdd<na::U1>>::Output as na::DimName>::Value * <<D as na::DimNameAdd<na::U1>>::Output as na::DimName>::Value`
  |
  = help: the trait `std::ops::Mul` is not implemented for `<<D as na::DimNameAdd<na::U1>>::Output as na::DimName>::Value`
  = help: consider adding a `where <<D as na::DimNameAdd<na::U1>>::Output as na::DimName>::Value: std::ops::Mul` bound
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `na::allocator::Allocator<f32, <D as na::DimNameAdd<na::U1>>::Output, <D as na::DimNameAdd<na::U1>>::Output>` for `na::DefaultAllocator`
```

Trying to follow the error message leads down a rabbit hole with the next trait error message. I have looked at the API of nalgebra, which does not contain such complicated trait chains. For example the `to_homogenous` method. I am not sure if my approach is even the right way.

There is also the trait `Dim` with corresponding `DimAdd` and `DimSum`, however since that part of `nalgebra` is not really documented,

I don't know if I am on the right path - or if what I want to do is even possible.

Comment: Doing so leads down a rabbit whole, with the next trait error message. I have looked at the API of nalgebra, which does not contain such complicated trait chains. For example the `to_homogenous` method. I am not sure if my approach is even the right way.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I fixed the typo (`na::Matrix` -> `na::MatrixN`). Compilation now leads to the error above. Unfortunately, it seems that `nalgebra` is not supported by the Rust playground.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This post](https://discourse.nphysics.org/t/using-nalgebra-in-generics/90/3) pointed me in the right direction. The way to do this is in `nalgebra` is a little bit convoluted:

```
extern crate nalgebra as na;

use crate::na::{Dim, DimName, DimNameAdd, DimNameSum, MatrixN, U1, DefaultAllocator};
use crate::na::allocator::Allocator;

pub struct Homogenous<D: Dim + DimName>
where
    D: DimNameAdd<U1>,
    DefaultAllocator: Allocator<f32, DimNameSum<D, U1>, DimNameSum<D, U1>>,
{
    mat: MatrixN<f32, DimNameSum<D, U1>>,
}
```

Hopefully, these type of generic manipulations become more ergonomic in future versions of Rust and nalgebra, since these rather cumbersome type annotations need to be repeated quite often.

By the way, just storing these generic types in a struct still requires the `DefaultAllocator`:

```
extern crate nalgebra as na;

use crate::na::{Dim, DimName, MatrixN, DefaultAllocator};
use crate::na::allocator::Allocator;

pub struct Homogenous<D: Dim + DimName>
where
    DefaultAllocator: Allocator<f32, D, D>,
{
    mat: MatrixN<f32, D>,
}
```

Comment: [This thread](https://github.com/anowell/are-we-learning-yet/issues/14) might have some interesting insights. The complexity of these methods is usually narrowed down to the lack of [const generics](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44580).